# Scrapy ITEM_PIPELINES warning

Tags: python, scrapy

I have the following in my settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['mybot.pipelines.custompipeline']
```

But when I start scrapy, I get the following warning.

> /lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/pipeline/**init**.py:21: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: ITEM_PIPELINES defined as a list or a set is deprecated, switch to a dict
>     category=ScrapyDeprecationWarning, stacklevel=1)

It still seems to be working properly. But, what do I need to do in order to remove this warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

see scrapy documentation for [Activating an Item Pipeline component](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#activating-an-item-pipeline-component), for example:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'myproject.pipeline.custompipeline': 300,
}
```

> The integer values you assign to classes in this setting determine the order they run in- items go through pipelines from order number low to high. It’s customary to define these numbers in the 0-1000 range.

Answer (score 1):

And of course you will need to do it in settings.py file of your project file..