# How do I run a script for a minute, stop its execution, and then start it again?

Tags: python, service, packet-capture

I'm currently working on a script that is to be run for a particular amount of time(let's say a minute), and then has to stop its execution for like 5 seconds and then start executing again(this cycle keeps on repeating), without fail. The script is in Python 3.x and runs on Ubuntu environment. So creating a Service/Daemon of the same would also work(although the execution of the script has to stop for a few seconds).

It's basically using Scapy Module for packet sniffing while capturing Live and then doing some analysis on those captured packets, before inserting the data in the database. When i stop the execution of the script by pressing `Ctrl+C` it stops, and then inserts data in the DB and not in parallel. Although it'd be better if this process gets in parallel and the script never has to stop executing, but till then I need a workaround for the same.

**My Approach:**

```
import scapy

def main():
    capture = LiveCapture(interface = "<some interface>", filter="<some filter>")
    count = 0
    for pkt in capture:
        #DO SOMETHING

        insert_in_DB()   #--------This happens only when I stop the execution.
        if count == 100:
            count = 0
            #back to main()
```

So, you 
         get the general idea of what my code is trying to do, right? But I want this to happen after every 1 minute, where after running for 1 minute, the code execution stops so that the data can be entered into the DB and then start again after 5 or less seconds.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I suppose you could use the sleep() method to suspend execution for a time. But this sounds more like a job for multi-threading or multiprocessing to execute database and other logic concurrently.

Comment: @paisanco Yes sir, something that runs them in parallel. Also, sleep() seemed a viable option but it only delays the further execution of the code for a few seconds, but does not stop it's execution.   And my DB Insert takes place only when you stop it's execution.

Comment: I don't understand why do you need to stop the execution of the program to store the scraped data. In Scrapy you can handle both serial or parallel database storing.

Comment: @MarcoD.G. If you could help me achieve DB Insertion without a possible need to stop execution of the program, using Scapy, I'd be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **MySQLdb** to use MySQL in python and [**Twisted adbapi**](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/rdbms.html) to perform async connections.

**MySQLdb:**

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
pip3 install mysql-python
```

**Twisted adbapi:**

```
pip3 install twisted
```

---

**Spider.py**

```
def parse(self, response):
    yield {
        'item_id' : ...
        'item_name': ...
        ...
    }
```

Add a `MySQLStorePipeline` to `pipelines.py` and declare it in `settings.py`:

**pipelines.py**

```
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi       #pip3 install twisted
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.conf import settings
import MySQLdb.cursors

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
    #A pipeline to store the item in a MySQL database.
    #This implementation uses Twisted's asynchronous database API.


    def __init__(self):
        dbargs = settings.get('DB_CONN')
        self.dbpool = adbapi.ConnectionPool(
            "MySQLdb",
            cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
            **dbargs
        )

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # run db query in thread pool
        query = self.dbpool.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
        query.addErrback(self.handle_error)
        return item

    def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
        # create record if doesn't exist. 
        # all this block run on it's own thread
        item_id = item['item_id']
        db_table = 'your_table_name'

        try:
            tx.execute("SELECT 1 FROM " + db_table + " WHERE item_id = %s", (item_id, ))
        except:
            print("## Query Failed:" + str(tx._last_executed))

        result = tx.fetchone()

        if result:
            log.msg("Item already stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            try:
                tx.execute(\
                    "INSERT INTO " + db_table + " (item_id, item_name) "
                    "values (%s, %s)",
                    (item_id, item['item_name'])
                )
                log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
            except:
                print("## Query Failed:" + str(tx._last_executed))

    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

**Settings.py**

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'your_project.pipelines.your_projectPipeline': 300,
    'your_project.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline': 600,
} #note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37442907/scrapy-attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-iteritems

DB_CONN = {    
    'db': 'your_db',
    'user': 'your_username',
    'passwd': 'your_password',
    'host': 'your_host',
    'charset': 'utf8',
    'use_unicode': True,
}
```

**notes**:

Replace all your_***** with your SQL credentials.

The code above assumes that your SQL table has only 2 columns: 'item_id', 'item_name', of course, you can modify it in the INSERT INTO query.

If you have any problem leave a comment.

Comment: Thank you for going out of your way to provide me with this answer, Sir. Will get back to you as soon as I'm done implementing this. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I think you misread my module name. It's not Scrapy(which is a web-scraping tool). Its Scapy- a packet manipulation tool for python. :P

Comment: @DevanshuMisra ehmm, sorry, but I misleading 'Scapy' with 'Scrapy' so sorry, they are 2 completly different lib.

Comment: Thank you for this though. I think the implementation remains the same. Only the type of data and the module used changes, the rest of it is I guess implementing multi-threading only for my program, which can be of good use. THANKS ANYWAY, SIR!